# Spring Java config message convertor priority

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-java-config

I have defined two convertors like this using Spring Java config. I always get a XML response unless I specified the 'Accept=applicaiton/json' in the HTTP header. Is there a way to set the default convertor to be JSON instead of XML convertor.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"})
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter() {
    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
    return xmlConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(jsonConverter());
    converters.add(xmlConverter());
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

Here is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product")
public
@ResponseBody
BSONObject getProducts(@RequestParam String ids,
                       @RequestParam(required = false) String types) {


    List<BSONObject> products = commonDataService.getData(ids, types);

    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following configuration, it sets up the default Content negotiation strategy(based on article [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }
}
```

Another option will be to provide other ways of specifying the content format, if `Accept` header is not feasible, an option could be to specify an extension `/myuri/sample.json` which would be returned as a json.